# How to scrape tables after on click button for multiple pages listed in a CSV file? Selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, chrome-web-driver

I would like to scrape all the information in a table presented multiple URLs using the pd.read_html function. An example of a website would be: https://www.top40.nl/10cc/10cc-donna-5867 which I import through a csv file.

After entering the website and clicking on the tab 'Songinfo' the table with all relevant information becomes visible. Please find my code below. Python gives the error: No table found and/ or cannot parse from list. Happy to hear any advice on how to correct my code:

```
df_list = []

with open(r"C:\Users\nlvijn02\Documents\Personal documents\Sony\Test_input_links.csv") as file:    
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row[0])
        driver.get(row[0])
                
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='#songinfo']").click()
        
        table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="songinfo"]/table""")
    
        df_list.append(pd.read_html(table))
            
    df = pd.concat(df_list)
        
driver.close()        
df.to_csv("details.csv")
```

Please find below the HTML code of the table:

```
<div id="songinfo" class="tab-pane active" aria-expanded="true"><h2>Songinformatie</h2><table class="table-songinfo"><tbody><tr><th>Artiest</th><td><a data-linktype="artist" href="https://www.top40.nl/top40-artiesten/10cc">10cc</a></td></tr><tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th style="text-align: left;">A-kant</th></tr><tr><th>Titel</th><td>
                                                                                                            Donna                                                                                                   </td></tr><tr><th>Lengte</th><td>
                                                                                                            02:55
                                                                                                    </td></tr><tr><th>Componist(en)</th><td>
                                                                                                            Kevin Godley, Lol Creme
                                                                                                    </td></tr><tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th style="text-align: left;">B-kant</th></tr><tr><th>Titel</th><td>
                                                                                                            Hot Sun Rock
                                                                                                    </td></tr><tr><th>Lengte</th><td>
                                                                                                            03:00
                                                                                                    </td></tr><tr><th>Componist(en)</th><td>
                                                                                                            Eric Stewart, Graham Gouldman
                                                                                                    </td></tr><tr><th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th></tr><tr><th>Platenlabel</th><td>
                                                                                                    UK
                                                                                            </td></tr><tr><th>Catalogusnr</th><td>
                                                                                                    UK 6
                                                                                            </td></tr><tr><th>Hoogste positie UK</th><td>
                                                                                                    2
                                                                                            </td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: If you visit the site given by `print(row[0])` do you see the elements you're looking for? It's best if you create a method `find_elements` that you try on the content of one of the rows in the CSV. first. If it works for one, then iterate over all the URLs.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. However, that is what I do at 'table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="songinfo"]/table""")'. This is the XPATH of the table I want to scrape the data from.

Comment: @arundeepchohan Thank you for your answer, however when I enter only 1 ", it will give me: invalid syntax. That's why I enter it three times. Unfortunately this is not the solution.. I have added the HTML of the table if that helps maybe. I think I did something wrong with the loop?

Comment: table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='songinfo']/table") It's a single object not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_list = []

with open(r"C:\Users\nlvijn02\Documents\Personal documents\Sony\Test_input_links.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row[0])
        driver.get(row[0])

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='#songinfo']").click()

        table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="songinfo"]/table""")

        df_list.append(pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML')))

    df = pd.concat(df_list)

driver.close()
df.to_csv("details.csv")
```

I modified 2 lines in your code.

1. find_elements_by_xpath => find_element_by_xpath
2. table => table.get_attribute('outerHTML')

I'd be very happy if you test my code and let me know the result.
Best Regards

Comment: Thank you so much Ahmed, it worked perfectly to scrape all the data from each table. The only thing that I struggle with is how to put the data in a csv file. As the 'df = pd.concact(df_list) does not work. I get this error: 
cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only series and dataframe objs are valid. Do you have any advice for this as well?

Comment: You can modify "df_list.append" to "df_list.extend".

Comment: You can modify "df_list.append" to "df_list.extend", because the return value of pd.read_html is a type of list, so I think that you'd better use df_list.extend rather than df_list.append.